# Internationalize emails from sorcery with delayed_job in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, delayed-job, sorcery

I have Rails 3.2 application which uses Sorcery for authentication and delayed_job for async emails delivery.

This configuration works just fine, but I need to add antoher language to the application. 
The question is how to tweak sorcery and delayed_job to send emails in language which corresponds to I18n.locale.

PS. I know I can add locale parameter to functions in UserMailer, but I can't understand how to override generic_send_email to pass current locale.

Comment: if you have a delayed job, you would first have to save or pass the user locale through to the job and then use that locale in the mailer.

Comment: The thing is: I don't call the mailer from my code. Sorcery does it.